# Installed Ubuntu along with Windows but neither boots now

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 along with windows 10 in my Dell Inspiron 7390. It gave me a grub installation error and later when I tried to install Ubuntu again, it did not give me any error and the installation was successful. But when I boot the laptop, it was directly taking me to Windows without showing the grub screen. I disabled the fast startup and Secure Boot options.

When I was trying to fix this issue, Windows Boot Manager also disappeared and now when I boot the laptop, it says `No bootable devices found`.

There is only "ubuntu" in the BIOS sequence. It had *Windows Boot Manager* and *UEFI Hard Drive* earlier.

When I insert the bootable USB stick and open the terminal while "Trying Ubuntu without installing" and run `fdisk -l`, it gives me this.

[image: Partitions]

It looks like both Windows and Ubuntu are present, but neither of them boots. I have tried installing grub manually, mounting, chrooting and Boot-Repair, but none of them worked. Boot-Repair reported that it repaired successfully, but nothing happened and the problem still exists. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G4VHr3ydbP/) is the pastebin link that Boot-Repair gave me. Below are a few commands I ran.

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1/mnt
grub-install --efi-directory=/dev/nvme0n1p1
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/dev/..p1 --bootloader-id=grub
```

[image: Mounting and installing grub]

[image: Installing grub]

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
```

[image: Grub installation failed]

[Update]
I tried using the rescatux tool and that also does not seem to work. This is the output of "Check UEFI partition status" 
[image: Rescatux]
I get the same output for the other partitions too. When I try easy GNU/ Linux boot fix, everything looks fine but the nothing happens. Once I remove the USB and boot, the "no bootable devices found" error still exists.
[image: Easy GNU/Linux boot fix]

Comment: I'll try it out and update the question.

Comment: @karel It didn't work.